# Adding rows to DataTable is HALF working

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to "view" a 2d array in the debug visualizer.

I have written this method and try to set a break point on the return statement.

When I count the rows in `dt` - there are the number I expect. BUT the VS Visualizer is not showing any rows only columns...

```
private DataTable ViewArray(double[,] A)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow newRow;

    for (int c = 0; c <= A.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add();
    }

    for (int r = 0; r <= A.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        newRow = dt.NewRow();

        for (int c = 0; c <= A.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
        {
            newRow[c] = A[r, c];
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: So we should fix the visualizer? Can you show the `double[,]` that you've used and where you have set the breakpoint? **Edit** It works for me: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160422/6bqq5qyq.jpg

Comment: @TimSchmelter That;s really odd when I declare test "arr" same as you it works. BUT when I use me large array it does not!